# How to decode a set of values encoded in an unknown encoding stored as hex

Tags: encoding, hex, decode

A software I am using encodes a set of floats as a hex string.

8e 3c 86 71 b8 25 ac bf 01 ab bc c4 08 69 aa ad 3f 01 a3 78 60 8c c6 fd c5 3f 01

I know the values accurate to two decimal places.

-.05, .06, .17

How would I go about figuring out the encoding?

Comment: As a first step please collect and provide as much background information as possible like name of software, operating system, programming language of the software, encryption, compression, etc. and describe the way you obtained the hex string and the decimal numbers.

Comment: Hi Markus, the question was meant to be broad.  But if I don't get any more generally applicable advice I will return with individual specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is IEEE 754 floating point, double precision ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), little endian ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)), separated by `01` byte, probably some proprietary indicator for the data type.

Step 1: Extract 8-byte words

```
8e 3c 86 71 b8 25 ac bf
ab bc c4 08 69 aa ad 3f
a3 78 60 8c c6 fd c5 3f
```

Step 2: Optionally revert from little to big endian, depending on the converter you are going to use

```
bf ac 25 b8 71 86 3c 8e
3f ad aa 69 08 c4 bc ab
3f c5 fd c6 8c 60 78 a3
```

Step 3: Convert from binary double to human readable decimal format, here for testing done manually with online service [baseconvert.com](https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point) (64-bit hexadecimal input)

```
-0.05497528444095066413321859499774291180074214935302734375
0.057940752334951405033702798164085834287106990814208984375
0.1718071160730164359531357831656350754201412200927734375
```

How to decode unknown formats:

In this case I new that there are three floats. I counted the bytes and saw that there are 27, which is divisible by 3. So I split the bytes in 9 byte words and saw that there is the pattern of 8 bytes followed by `01`. 8-byte binary floats are well known, so I checked if the sample fits to the standard. Well and it did.

If you have no clue after simply watching at the data:

1. Check if the encoded file has a well known magic cookie
2. If possible change the input to simple values like 0 or 1 or 2 and observe what the software does with it.
3. Look out for standard encodings, compression methods or encryptions that are normally used for this kind of data.
4. Collect as much information about the software as possible.
5. Try to reengineer the software with an appropriate tool.

Comment: Hi markus!  Thanks much for your reply - it is certainly useful. Regardign the question, though, more broadly, is there a general approach to reverse engineering / figuring out an unknown encoding?  This is one of several problems faced including a more complex data structure.  So any commentary on figuring out the encoding, or approaching an unknown encoding would be helpful.

Comment: Handwave ahead: Intuitively it seems like a simple / neat enough problem that someone would have written some sort of entropy minimizing brute force, detector for delimiters or patterns via alignments, or at a tool to subset and scan through common encodings.

Comment: I added some general information. If you are asking for some automatic, generic encoding detector and decipher tool that is able to do this, then I must admit that I don’t know one. But that wasn’t the original question, was it?

Comment: Thank you.  I meant it to be more general but wasn't clear on that point.

Comment: @nate, if you find something general then you can post it here for others :)